# Problemas con PHPMailer y Outlook

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

Tengo graves problemas al tratar de utilizar la función *$mail* y no tengo idea en donde esté el error; se supone que se hizo una función send_mail en la pagina del sistema como la siguiente:

```
function send_mail(){
    var parametros = new FormData($('#send_m')[0]);

$.ajax({
url:'../send_ma.php',
type:'POST',
data: parametros,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success:function mostrar(resp){
$('#respb').html(resp);}});}
```

Los datos los jala de un pequeño formulario llamado **send_m** y después se supone que manda al PHP **send_ma.php** que se tiene configurado con outlook; el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
header('charset=utf-8');
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader<br>
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP(); SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
// Usuario de correo y contraseña
$mail->Username = "micorre@dominio.com>";
$mail->Password = "micontra";

$mail->FromName = "Panchito"; 
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['email_pa']);

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->IsHTML(true); // Habilitamos el uso de HTML
$mail->Subject = $_POST['asunto'];
$mail->Body = $_POST['a_body'];

$mail->send();
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#en_mail1b').css({display:'none'});
    saving_pac()
    alert('El mensaje se ha enviado correctamente');
    //window.close()<br>
    //window.opener.document.location.reload();
    </script>";
?>
```

La verdad estoy muy frustrado porque no encuentro en donde tenga el error; si algún buen samaritano me puede ayudar se lo agradecería infinitamente...

**P.D. El proyecto está de manera local en XAMPP**

Comment: Por favor no uses etiquetas html para hacer saltos de línea (vaya que fue cansado removerlas), cuando necesites formatear código selecciona el fragmento deseado y presiona `ctrl + k` y queda formateado

Comment: Atrapa el error mediante lo siguiente, para saber qué puede ser:                                                     
       if (!$correo->Send()) {
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;
        }